# how we enter character in senkeys+ selenium

Tags: java, arrays, selenium-webdriver

```
String str ='here i am entring some string'
```

I am trying to encrypt the string with the help of "base64"

```
byte[] encode = Base64.encodeBase64(str.getBytes());    
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='login_div']/form/div[2]/p[2]/input")).sendKeys(encode);
```

But in `sendkeys` they are not accepting (encode) value they have thrown an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws compile time error because as "Sendkeys" method can receive only character sequence(readable sequence of char values). So if your requirement is to send that piece of a byte array into that particular textbox/text field then try this piece of code.

reference for char sequence: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html

```
driver.findElement(By.id(".//[@id='login_div']/form/div[2]/p[2]/input")).sendKeys(encode.toString());
```

here I'm sending that byte array as a string. Let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: Thanks @krishna Reddy your above logic is working fine for me

Comment: Welcome Piyush  :)

Answer (score -1):

Everything you have did is correct but we need to decrypt the string before sending it to the selenium sendkeys. I have created a separate helper class to perform the encryption and decryption as below.

```
public class Helper {

/**
 * Static helper method to Encrypt a string
 * @param word - Pass the word that needs to be encrypted
 * @return - Returns the encrypted String for the word
 */

public static String encrypter(String word)
{
    String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(word.getBytes());
    return encoded;
}

/**
 * Static helper method to decode the encrypted String
 * @param word - Pass the encrypted String which needs to be encrypted
 * @return - Returns the decrypted String
 */
public static String decrypter(String word)
{
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(word.getBytes());
    return new String(decoded);

}}
```

Now in our selenium we can use it something like this.

```
String str = "Enter the String to Encrypt";
String encoded = Helper.encrypter(str);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='login_div']/form/div[2]/p[2]/input")).sendKeys(Helper.decrypter(encoded));
```

Note - I am using java 1.8.0_121. Base64 class methods implementation may slightly differ in previous versions but the concept is same.